# PHP page does not load when I try to show an error message

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I am trying to show a duplicate error on a form, but this function crashes the page and the page does not load. How can I configure file *php.ini* for this?

This is the function with that I am trying to show the error messages on the form page:

```
public function getError($error) {
    if(!in_array($error, $this->errorArray)) {
        $error = "";
    }
    return "<span class='errorMessage'>$error</span>";
}
```

This is the function which I am trying to use to get the error in the array:

```
private function validateEmails($em) {
    $checkEmailQuery = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT email FROM member_forms WHERE email='$em'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkEmailQuery) != 0) {
        array_push($this->errorArray, Strings::$emExists);

        return;
    }
}
```

These functions double-check with the database and if an error occurs, `<?php echo $account->getError(Strings::$emExists); ?>` should display it, but it does not and the page doesn't load.

When the error occurs, it goes until the error, but it does not render anything and the body of the HTML page goes empty

#### HTML

```html
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <p>
            <?php echo $account->getError(Strings::$fnCharacters); ?>

            <div class="col-md-3 indent-small">
                <div class="form-group internal">
                    <input class="form-control" id="firstName"
                        name="firstName" type="text"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        style="width: 180%;/*! padding-right: ; */margin: 0px 0px 0px 12px;"
                        value="<?php getInputValue('firstName')?>" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 indent-small"
                style="margin-left: 15px;width: 25%;">
                <div class="form-group internal">
                    <input class="form-control" id="lastName"
                        name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"
                        style="width: 188%;/*! padding-left: 33px; */margin-left: 56px;"
                        value="<?php getInputValue('lastName')?>" required>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2" for="email"
            style="margin-left: 0;width: 28%;/*! float: left; */">E-mail
            Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $account->getError(Strings::$emExists); ?>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                            type="email" placeholder="Your E-mail..."
                            style="width: 156%;"
                            required>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to show much more code. Please provide a [mcve]  Possibly with a rendered HTML page

Comment: where is the `errorMessage()` function?

Comment: yes, i try to, as this is only one validate function just to explain the example, but main reason the error occurs is errorMessage() function which do not allow the page to load. and I have added the html code too

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy i have attached code in my question

Comment: @mplungjan please let me know if you can help

Comment: "crashes the page and the page does not load"
Do you get an error? Please enable error reporting on top of your PHP script and see if you get an error.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: yes @aliirfaan exactly

Comment: @Lilly, It seems like there isn't any error with your code. I'd like to dig into the issue in more detail for you. Please contact me directly with your server info.

Comment: Have you checked the error log from the web server? It can be quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used that code you posted works totally fine on my local host. Have you checked the server used on your new hosting?

If it's different, then the same code might not work as expected on another server. There are several factors affecting that. [Click here](https://www.php.net/install) to get tips on that.

You can also use the [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function. It might help in further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this code should fix this error:

```
if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {

    /* a bunch of code to insert into the DB */
    // if inserted echo the following messges
    if ($r) {
        echo "<script> alert('Saved')</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<b>Oops! we have an issu </b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am already using this code for in my form handler page but the main concern is to show the error, the code i showed works really fine on my other website but do not seems to be working here.

Comment: @Lilly It seems to be working just fine, where doesn't it work?

Comment: as the upper suggested answer suggestedd, different server might make problems running my code.